# Calculate NTC Temprature. but witout series resistor

Tags: arduino, analog, adc, thermistor

Hello I have NTC Connected on PCB which configure as shown in following schematics.
[image: schematics]

The problem is that I can not apply Steinhart-Hart equation because there is no resistance connected in series to calculate voltage drop in MCU and evaluate NTC resistance. Is there any way to figure voltage drop across NTC without second resistance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this circuit is connected to opamp buffer or ADC with large input imedance, then you will always get the 3.3V voltage. So the answer is: you can't connect the NTC in that way to be able to measure the temperature.

Comment: I was sure that this configuration had an issue. thanks for confirming this.  I'll tell my client to update it with R2 in series.